# how to get parameters in url laravel view or blade

Tags: php, laravel

My question code is below,

```
{{ route('report.edit', array('id' => $report->uid,  'p_'.$param->name => $param->value,  'p_'.$param->name => $param->value))}}">
```

Output is: `https://laracast.com/report/12/edit?p_paramname=paramvalue`

But i have multiple parameters name and value, its not taking only last paramname and value is taking. If you print {{$param->name}} getting 2 param values.

Comment: post your route

Comment: because you have the same key name and value ... `$param->name` and `$param->value` are not changing every time you use them ... `['a' => 'a', 'a' => 'a'] === ['a' => 'a']`

Comment: Can you post the result if you use the {{$param->name}}?

Comment: Please share more details about your expectation - how should the generated URL look like? The given array contains **two** values under the same key, and PHP does not support that

Answer (score 0):

That is just because you have the same keys 
Look at this

```
'p_'.$param->name => $param->value,  'p_'.$param->name => $param->value
```

Just use the separate keys and this will fix your problem 
For example
Look at this

```
'p_1_'.$param->name => $param->value,  'p_2_'.$param->name => $param->value
```